# "Deregister" plugin from frontend or specific pages?

Tags: plugins

Is is possible to stop plugin from loading on general frontend or on specific pages, similar like we can do with deregistering scripts and styles? Plugins are not mine and I only need them in the admin dashboard. Inspecting website with Query Monitor I noticed that they do additional useless queries like this

```
SELECT option_value
FROM nk_options
WHERE option_name = 'wp-smush-resize'
LIMIT 1

SELECT option_value
FROM nk_options
WHERE option_name = 'wp-smush-resize_sizes'
LIMIT 1
```

I can't see the point of this. In this example plugin is WP Smush which only optimizes images when they are uploaded in backend. But there are a few more like WP/LR Sync and others, and they are not related to frontend... Is there something I could do on my theme files or inside Wordpress to stop them from doing additional database queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `/your-page-slug/` with your desired page where you want to disable the plugin and `plugin-folder/plugin-main-file.php` is plugin directory and plugin main file name with `.php` extension.

```
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'the_dramatist_disable_plugin_on_certain_page' );

function the_dramatist_disable_plugin_on_certain_page($plugins){

    if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/your-page-slug/') === FALSE && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin/') === FALSE) {
        $key = array_search( 'plugin-folder/plugin-main-file.php' , $plugins );
        if ( false !== $key ) unset( $plugins[$key] );
    }

    return $plugins;
}
```

Hope this piece of code help you.

Comment: Thank you, I finally managed to do it after placing the code inside mu-plugins